# 62.5% Font Size Not Working

Tags: font-size

I'm using the 62.5% font-size trick, and while it works on some bits of text, it doesn't work for others.

Any ideas?

```
body {
font: 62.5% HelveticaNeue, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

For example, this isn't 16px: http://jsfiddle.net/vfGJa/6/

Comment: Can you create minimalist, self-contained example (in the question, then perhaps *additionally* on http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating how it applies to some text but not other text?

Comment: Sorry dude, and thanks for that link. I didn't know how to accept, thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the jsfiddle link, the problem is that `em` is like a relative value, so that element is recieving first the size `62.5%`, than is increased to `1.4em`, and than increased again to `1.6em` but based on previous `1.4em` value. Remove that `1.4em` and you'll see that you get the size you're looking for.

Sorry my bad english.

Comment: You, my friend, are marvelous! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the REM unit instead of EM: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem

Answer (score 0):

Some elements don't inherit font properties. Use a Css Reset file and this will work fine.

Comment: *"Some elements don't inherit font properties"* Which ones?

Comment: I can remember that table does not inherit

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : I've made some tests, `table` doesn't inherit when you don't declare the doctype.